# How to reach ViewModel object from GestureListener onX handlers

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, gesture

I'm writing a simple Kotlin Android app that must show images on the screen and scroll through the list by using a gesture, Fling to be specific. I'm new to Android development and Kotlin.

I'm using a ViewModel derived class to store the app information.

I have been able to show the image and scroll through the list using buttons. When the button are pressed a counter in the ViewModel with the image position in the list of images is shown. For that I have used data binding.

But when I implemented the Gesture detection logic I realized that from inside the onFling method I have no access to the ViewModel data, so I cant update the counter so I'm unable to interact with the app status. The onFling method is called properly and I'm having enough information to implement the logic, but no access to modify the data in the ViewModel.

I'm sure there must be a way to do that, but I have been unable to find a way.

Without the possibility to reach an to modify ViewModel data all the Gestures framework seems quite useless.

<s>I don't think that my code will clarify the question but I can post it if requested.</s> (Thanks @Andy)

This is the Activity class code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val _data: AppData by viewModels()
    private lateinit var _binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var _detector: GestureDetectorCompat

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        _binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        // Binding app data to the View
        _binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        _binding.data = _data

        // Check permissions
        .
        . Irrelevant code
        .

        // Initialize gesture Listener
        _detector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, MyGestureListener())
        val focusImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.photo_focus)
        focusImage.setOnTouchListener {_ , event -> _detector.onTouchEvent(event) }

        // Load the available photos
        .
        . Irrelevant code
        .
    }

    private class MyGestureListener: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()           {
         override fun onDown(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onDown: $event")
            return true
        }

        override fun onFling(
            event1: MotionEvent,
            event2: MotionEvent,
            velocityX: Float,
            velocityY: Float
        ): Boolean {
            Log.d("Gesture", "onFling: $event1 $event2 $velocityX $velocityY")

            // NO ACCESS TO ViewModel!!!
            // I will like to do something like
            val data = some_way_get_ViewModel()

            if (velocityX > 1000)
                data.moveNext()

            if (velocityZ < -1000)
                data.movePrev()

            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will probably get smacked for not showing your code, or at least a sample project that outlines your problem. At this point no one will really be able to help until they see the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this question still open? If it is, I just faced a similar problem and found a solution myself.

You can add a viewModel constructor to your MyGestureListener class like this:

```
private class MyGestureListener(private val viewModel: MainActivityVM?):
 GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        
        override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            viewModel?.yourMutableLiveData?.value = true
            return true
        }
// You can call other override methods too.
}
```

And then pass your viewModel in your MainActivity like this:

```
        // Initialize gesture Listener
        _detector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, MyGestureListener(_binding.data))
```

Your viewModel itself cannot extend GestureDetector class because your viewModel cannot accept touch inputs. That is done by your activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will try you answer and come with feedback.